# javascript not working

Tags: css

```
<script>
    //Using document.body.contains.
    if(document.contains(document.getElementByClassName[0]('wcEmoticon'))){
        document.getElementsByClassName[0]('wcMessageContent').element.classList.add("opened");
    } else{
        document.getElementsByClassName[0]('wcMessageContent').element.classList.remove("opened");
    }
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    require(['jquery'], function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var wcMessageContent = $(".wcMessageContent");
            if(wcMessageContent.find("img").hasClass("wcEmoticon")){
                wcMessageContent.addClass("opened");
            }
        });
    } );
</script>
```

Give a try - Thanks